# How to map 1-D array of values with latitude and longitude?

Tags: python, json, geolocation, geojson

I've this [data](https://pastebin.com/CzZxV1nu) which I want to map with latitude/longitude for visualisation purpose in qgis. But the problem is the array is 1-D and longitude range is 0-360 . So, I've no idea if it starts from `[-180,180]` or `[180,-180]`. I tried using the below code, but it doesn't get mapped properly. Can anyone help me in parsing this json:

```
latittude = -90
longitude = -180
count = 0
for i in range(0,316):
    for j in range(0,544):
        longitude += 0.6617647058823529
        aqi = aqi_data[count]
        count += 1
        if float(aqi) == 0:
            continue
        with open('pollution.csv', 'a') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            data = [[count,latittude,longitude,aqi]]
            a.writerows(data)
    latittude += 0.5727848101265823
    longitude = -180
```

Comment: Where are you running into errors? What makes you think the data "doesn't get mapped properly"?

Comment: Because the latitude value in some cases increases to `90.42721518987327` which is invalid. Even though if I ignore the range issue, whenever I plot the data in qgis, it gives wrong value > 150 in ocean, which is not possible.